# Intel compilers cannot handle absolute value of small number

Tags: gcc, floating-point, precision, icc

I am facing some very weird rounding errors when compiling my code with `intel 2018` when compared to `gcc 7.2.0`. I'm simply looking into taking the absolutely value of extrememly small number:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double numa = -1.3654159537789158e-08;
  double numb = -7.0949094162313382e-08;
  if (isnan(numa))
      printf("numa is nan \n");
  if (isnan(numb))
      printf("numb is nan \n");

  printf("abs(numa) %.17g \n", abs(numa));
  printf("abs(numb) %.17g \n", abs(numb));

  if ((isnan(numa) || (abs(numa) < DBL_EPSILON)) || (isnan(numb) || (abs(numb) < DBL_EPSILON))) {
    printf("x %.17g y %.17g DBL_E %.17g \n", numa, numb, DBL_EPSILON);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output when compiling the code with `gcc 7.2.0`, which is expected:

```
$ ./a.out
abs(numa) 1.3654159537789158e-08
abs(numb) 7.0949094162313382e-08
```

But it is a different story for `intel/2018`:

```
$ ./a.out
abs(numa) 2.0410903428666442e-314
abs(numb) 2.0410903428666442e-314
x -1.3654159537789158e-08 y -7.0949094162313382e-08 DBL_E 2.2204460492503131e-16
```

What could cause my version of Intel compilers to have such a huge difference?

Comment: Is that C? Whats cfloat? If it is c you should use fabs() not abs().

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer this question. In C++, the source you show should print the first output, not the second. So something may be wrong in your Intel software installation, or something may be wrong in how you built and execute the program, or you might have compiled a different source file (or version of the file) than you thought you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong function or wrong language**

Output with "gcc 7.2.0" is as expected because OP compiled with C++

With "intel/2018" the output is consistent with a forced C compilation.

With C, the `abs(numa)` converts `numa` to an `int` with the value of 0 and the below is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `"%.17g"` expects a `double` and not an `int`.

```
// In C UB:       vvvvv------vvvvvvvvv
printf("abs(numa) %.17g \n", abs(numa));
```

With the UB output of `"abs(numa) 2.0410903428666442e-314"`, we can do some forensics.

Typical 2.0410903428666442e-314 in [binary](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050046048052049048057048051052050056054054054052052050101045051049052) is

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11110110 00111101 01001110 00101110

This is consistent with some C compilations that pass a 32-bit `int 0` and then `printf()` retrieved that along with some other following junk as the expected `double`.

As UB, this result may vary from time-to-time, if output at all, yet is good indicator of the problem:  Compile in C++ or change to `fabs()` ([@dmuir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646506/intel-compilers-cannot-handle-absolute-value-of-small-number/53660892#comment94156395_53646506)) to take the absolute value of a `double` in both C++ and C.

---

Some kudos to OP for using `"%g"` (or `"%e"`) when debugging a floating point issues.  Far more informative the `"%f"`